# Excel VBA: Copy columns from workbook to new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not really great at coding so as much help as possible would be incredible. Basically here's what I want to do.

1. Export CSV from Website (No code required)
2. Open CSV in Excel (No code required)
3. Automatically remove rows that have a blank cell in certain column (Already coded)
4. Copy specific columns (ignoring header rows) to another workbook in specific order.

Column order is as follows: (S1 = Open CSV || S2 = New Workbook)

- S1.V = S2.A
- S1.B = S2.D
- S1.F = S2.V
- S1.H = S2.X
- S1.I = S2.J
- S1.L = S2.B

Step 3's code:

```
Columns("V:V").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot to consider when doing what you require, I have made some assumptions that you will need to code for if they are incorrect: -

- The destination already exists
- The destination has headers on row 1 but no content
- The destination is simply the first sheet in the destination workbook
- The source header row is row 1

Sample code: -

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim StrDestPath As String
Dim WkBk_Dest   As Workbook
Dim WkBk_Src    As Workbook
Dim WkSht_Dest  As Worksheet
Dim WkSht_Src   As Worksheet

'A reference to the destination
StrDestPath = "C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\Destination.xlsx"

'Connect to the source
Set WkBk_Src = ThisWorkbook
Set WkSht_Src = WkBk_Src.Worksheets(1)

'See if the destination is open already
For Each WkBk_Dest In Application.Workbooks
    If WkBk_Dest.FullName = StrDestPath Then Exit For
Next

'If it wasn't then open it
If WkBk_Dest Is Nothing Then
    Set WkBk_Dest = Application.Workbooks.Open(StrDestPath)
End If

'Connect to the destination
Set WkSht_Dest = WkBk_Dest.Worksheets(1)

'Per column mapping - Copy everythng from row 2 (assuming headers are on row 1 down to the last populated cell in that column
'and paste it into the required column in the destination
WkSht_Src.Range("V2:" & WkSht_Src.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Address).Copy WkSht_Dest.Range("A2")
WkSht_Src.Range("B2:" & WkSht_Src.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Address).Copy WkSht_Dest.Range("D2")
WkSht_Src.Range("F2:" & WkSht_Src.Range("F2").End(xlDown).Address).Copy WkSht_Dest.Range("V2")
WkSht_Src.Range("H2:" & WkSht_Src.Range("H2").End(xlDown).Address).Copy WkSht_Dest.Range("X2")
WkSht_Src.Range("I2:" & WkSht_Src.Range("I2").End(xlDown).Address).Copy WkSht_Dest.Range("J2")
WkSht_Src.Range("L2:" & WkSht_Src.Range("L2").End(xlDown).Address).Copy WkSht_Dest.Range("B2")

'Disconnect from destination worksheet
Set WkSht_Dest = Nothing

'save changes
WkBk_Dest.Save

'disconnect from destination workbook
Set WkBk_Dest = Nothing

'Disconnect from source
Set WkSht_Src = Nothing
Set WkBk_Src = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have also assumed the source to be the workbook I was coding in, this won't be possible in a CSV file so you might want to open it in the same way the destination is checked for and then opened, you also may want to add a flag to close them when done if they were not opened to begin with.

Finally, if the destination already has data use the `.end` function as shown in the sample to get the the last row.

Answer (score 1):

since you're working from CSV file, you don't have formats to carry along

therefore simple values pasting is what you need

try this

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyColumnsToAnotherWB(sourceWS As Worksheet, targetWs As Worksheet, sourceCols As String, targetCols As String)
    Dim sourceColsArr As Variant, targetColsArr As Variant
    Dim iCol As Long, nCols As Long

    sourceColsArr = Split(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(sourceCols), ",") '<--| make array out of string with delimiter
    targetColsArr = Split(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(targetCols), ",") '<--| make array out of string with delimiter

    nCols = UBound(sourceColsArr) '<--| count columns number to copy/paste
    If nCols <> UBound(targetColsArr) Then Exit Sub  '<--| exit if the two columns list haven't the same number of columns
    With sourceWS
        For iCol = 0 To nCols '<--|loop through source sheet columns
            With .Cells(1, sourceColsArr(iCol)).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, sourceColsArr(iCol)).End(xlUp).Row)
                targetWs.Columns(targetColsArr(iCol)).Resize(.Rows.Count).value = .value  '<--|paste values to corresponding target sheet column
            End With
        Next iCol
    End With
End Sub
```

which you can exploit as follows

Option Explicit

```
Sub main()

    Dim sourceCols As String, targetCols As String

    sourceCols = "V,B,F,H,I,L"
    targetCols = "A,D,V,X,J,B"
    CopyColumnsToAnotherWB ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet, Workbooks("columntest").Worksheets("test"), sourceCols, targetCols

End Sub
```

just change `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` and `Workbooks("columntest").Worksheets("test")` to your actual source and target workbooks and worksheets